# SQL - Display only values that don't meet a parameter.

Tags: sql

I am trying to bring back all the people that have not got a CNN_NDP_NO of 84.

As some people can have multiple CNN_NDP_NO's my code below only excludes a persons entry of 84, rather than the whole person.

```
SELECT
    CLIENT.CLN_SURNAME,
    CLIENT.CLN_NINO, 
    CLIENT.CLN_BIRTH_DATE
 FROM 
    MASTER.CLIENT, 
    MASTER.CLIENT_NDNP
 WHERE 
     MASTER.CLIENT_NDNP.CNN_NDP_NO not in (84)
     and 
     MASTER.CLIENT.CLN_NO = MASTER.CLIENT_NDNP.CNN_CLN_NO;
```

Here is a further explanation of the incorrect data coming back....

> Mr Farell has the following CNN_NDP_NO (43, 84, 90, 96)
>
> As Mr Farell has a CNN_NDP_NO of 84 he needs to be ignored from the output
>
> Instead I am getting three entries for Mr Farell (43, 90, 96). Obviously a distinct will give me one but for this instance I would like none.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `not exists`

```
SELECT c.CLN_SURNAME, c.CLN_NINO, c.CLN_BIRTH_DATE
FROM MASTER.CLIENT c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MASTER.CLIENT_NDNP ndnp
                  WHERE c.CLN_NO = ndnp.CNN_CLN_NO and ndnp.CNN_NDP_NO = 84
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply @Gordon Linoff. Unfortunately this has brought back results that don't have an CNN_NDP_NO.

I have tried 

             'and ndnp.CNN_NDP_NO in (null, 84) but has not fixed it. Any thoughts?'

Comment: @AmitSingh As mentioned I still seem to get null values. I have also tried.............
'code' SELECT c.CLN_SURNAME, c.CLN_NINO, c.CLN_BIRTH_DATE
FROM MASTER.CLIENT c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MASTER.CLIENT_NDNP ndnp
                  WHERE c.CLN_NO = ndnp.CNN_CLN_NO and ndnp.CNN_NDP_NO = 84 and ndnp.CNN_NDP_NO = NULL);

Comment: After searching more NINO's that appear I have also come across people that have 4 CNN_NDP_NO's (one of them being 84) so this solution has not worked, any thoughts?

Comment: @jack.r.barnes . . . I see no reason why that would affect this query.  Any `CLN_NO` with a record of "84" should be excluded entirely from the result set.  If you are getting duplicate results, then use `group by` or `select distinct`.